# ClassCastException

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception, dynamic-cast

i have two classes in java as:

```
class A {

 int a=10;

 public void sayhello() {
 System.out.println("class A");
 }
}

class B extends A {

 int a=20;

 public void sayhello() {
 System.out.println("class B");
 }

}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

 B b = (B) new A();
     System.out.println(b.a);
    }
}
```

at compile time it does not give error, but at runtime it displays an error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to B

Answer (score 16):

This happens because the *compile-time* expression type of `new A()` is `A` - which *could* be a reference to an instance of `B`, so the cast is allowed.

At execution time, however, the reference is just to an instance of `A` - so it fails the cast. An instance of just `A` *isn't* an instance of `B`. The cast only works if the reference really does refer to an instance of `B` or a subclass.

Answer (score 7):

B extends A and therefore B can be cast as A. However the reverse is not true.  An instance of A cannot be cast as B.

If you are coming from the Javascript world you may be expecting this to work, but Java does not have "[duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)".

Answer (score 1):

First do it like this :

```
  A aClass = new B();
```

Now do your Explicit casting, it will work:

```
   B b = (B) aClass;
```

That mean's Explicit casting must need implicit casting. elsewise Explicit casting is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the object of a child class you cannot typecast it into a superClass. Just look into the below examples

**Assumptions:** 
              Dog is the child class which inherits from Animal(SuperClass)

**Normal Typecast:**

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Animal animal = (Animal) dog;  //works
```

**Wrong Typecast:**

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Dog dog = (Dog) animal;  //Doesn't work throws class cast exception
```

**The below Typecast really works:**

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Animal animal = (Animal) dog;
dog = (Dog) animal;   //This works
```

A compiler checks the syntax it's during the run time contents are actually verified