# what in meaning of One o=(One) new Two(); in this programme. can anybody explain me, how this works?

Tags: java, casting, typecasting-operator

```
class One
{
    void show1()
    {
       System.out.println("super class");
    }

}

class Two extends One
{
    static void show2()
    {
       System.out.println("subclass");
    }


}
public class Cast 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
      One o=(One) new Two();
      o.show1();

    }

}
```

How does this statement work in this code `One o=(One) new Two();` ? Why can't I use like this
`Two o=(One) new Two();` ? I am confused of using casting, though o here is super class variable.. Why can't I refer sub class method using o?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How this statement work in this code **One o=(One) new Two();**

It means that an object of class `Two` is created and pointed by referenc of class `One`. Type casting is not required.

> why can't i use like this **Two o=(One) new Two();**

That is polymorphism. derived class can't point to base class.

**Rule of thumb:** Base class can point to any derived class. (not vice-versa). So, you can cast a derived class to base class and not other way round.

> though o here is super class variable. why can't i refer sub class method using o.

Right, but the actual object is of derived class and the reference is of base class. Only those methods of derived class will be accessible which are overriden in derived class.

Try following lines of code to see yourself:

```
Two obj = new One(); // Error
One obj = new Two(); // OK
Two obj = (Two) new One(); // Error
```

See this: [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html), [ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092796/classcastexception), and [Explanation of "ClassCastException" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/can-someone-explain-classcastexception-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Variable on the right side should of same type (or any subtype ) that of on the left side.

```
One o=(One) new Two();
```

Here `Two` is subtype of `One` so it can casted to `One` and can be used with reference variable of type `One`.

```
 Two o=(One) new Two();
```

Here you can cast object of type `Two` to `One` which is upcasting but you cant assign same casted object to reference variable of type `Two` because `One` is not a subclass of `Two`.

Given hierarchy is

```
One      
 |--> Two
```

`Two` can be used in place of `One` as it under One (sub type of One) in hierarchy but you cant do vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

> How this statement work

```
One o=(One) new Two();
```

Object of type `Two` is created on the heap. But reference `o` is cast to be reference to type `One`

Actually you can do:

```
Two o = new Two();
o.show1();
```

Because `Two` would also have `show1` method.

> why can't i use like this Two o=(One) new Two();

Reference mismatch. But you can do this

```
Two o=(Two)(One) new Two();
```

Answer (score 1):

**why can't i refer sub class method using o.**

Here **show2** method is only present in subclass and it is not present in superclass
and your object o is of derived class but you have to  override  method  in derived class 
so you can't access **show2.**