# Turn an object of Object into an object of different type?

Tags: java, class, oop, casting

Not sure if the question makes sense, but basically what I'm trying to do is this

```
Object obj = new Object();
BankAccount s = (BankAccount) obj;
System.out.println(s instanceof BankAccount);
```

I want this to return true, but it throws me a class cast exception error. Why can I not cast `BankAccount` to `Object`? Is it because `BankAccount` is automatically a subclass of `Object`?

Comment: class cast exception questions have been answered before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092796/classcastexception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type cast is telling the compiler "you think this `obj` has type `Object`, but trust me, it is actually a `BankAccount`". But you were lying about that, because it wasn't. The instance was only an `Object`.

The following would work:

```
Object obj = new BankAccount();
BankAccount s = (BankAccount) obj;
System.out.println(s instanceof BankAccount);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Henry's comment who explained that you could do the following:

```
Object obj = new BankAccount();
BankAccount s = (BankAccount) obj;
System.out.println(s instanceof BankAccount);
```

You should always keep in mind that variables are some kind of remote control.

The first line uses a `Object` remote control to control a `BankAccount`. This is possible because everything is an `Object`... this means you can use this remote control to control *all* objects. But you will also see that this control only supports operations that are defined in the `Object` class which means all `Objects` have.

The second line at the right side of the equation states that the referenced `Object` is actually a `BankAccount`. On the left side of the equation you force to create a new remote control that is able to control `BankAccount` objects.